# Access denied while starting phpmyadmin

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

When I start php my admin  : `dev01.dev/phpmyadmin` //dev01.dev is my localhost

It gives following error:

```
Welcome to phpMyAdmin

Error

MySQL said: Documentation
#2002 - No such file or directory
The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured).
Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.
Retry to connect
```

I edited the config file. Installed phpmyadmin again but same error.

My `/etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php`
is as below:

```
/* Authentication type */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'root';
/* Server parameters */
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
/* Select mysql if your server does not have mysqli */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;

/*
 * phpMyAdmin configuration storage settings.
 */

/* User used to manipulate with storage */
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlhost'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'pma';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = '';

/* Storage database and tables */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = 'phpmyadmin';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bookmarktable'] = 'pma__bookmark';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['relation'] = 'pma__relation';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_info'] = 'pma__table_info';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_coords'] = 'pma__table_coords';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pdf_pages'] = 'pma__pdf_pages';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['column_info'] = 'pma__column_info';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['history'] = 'pma__history';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_uiprefs'] = 'pma__table_uiprefs';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['tracking'] = 'pma__tracking';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_coords'] = 'pma__designer_coords';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['userconfig'] = 'pma__userconfig';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['recent'] = 'pma__recent';
```

What is lagging?

Answer (score 3):

// Authentication method (config, http or cookie based)

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type']     = 'http';
```

change config to http and try it.. 
& uncommand the server parameter

Comment: GOPI: thanks. Dont know started working which thing make it working!

Comment: @Karimkhan added it as an answer u can accept it, will help others too ,Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I realize you already solved it, but for future searches, this is the first thing I'd check:

Are you sure the MySQL server is running? I suggest trying to connect via command line client. Something like

```
mysql -u root -p
```